# How to show money format in C#

Tags: c#, sql

Hi I am having a problem in displaying the amount using this kind of format: 0,000.00 . I am using a grid view and data reader to show the amount from mySQL Database with Decimal as my datatype, my output only shows 0000.00

Can you help me how to resolve this problem? Thank You.

```
private void DisplayOrderDetails(int nOrderNo)

        {
            OpenConnection();

            SqlCommand cmdSelect = new SqlCommand();
            cmdSelect.Connection = cn;
            cmdSelect.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmdSelect.Transaction = trnOrder;
            cmdSelect.CommandText =
                "SELECT OrderDetailNo, OrderNo, PackagingOutside, Quantity, Unit, ProductNo, ProductName, " +
                "ProductSize, PackagingInside, " +
                "SellingDiscount1, SellingDiscount2, SellingDiscount3, SellingDiscount4, " +
                "SellingPrice, Amount FROM OrderDetails WHERE OrderNo = '"
                + nOrderNo + "'";

            SqlDataAdapter daDetail = new SqlDataAdapter();
            daDetail.SelectCommand = cmdSelect;

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            daDetail.Fill(ds, "OrderDetails");

            grdDetails.DataSource = null;
            grdDetails.DataSource = ds.Tables["OrderDetails"];

            DisplayTotal();
        }

 private void DisplayTotal()

        {
            double dTotal = 0;

            //for encountering errors in the future
            try
            {
                for (int nRow = 0;
                    nRow <= dsDetail.Tables["OrderDetails"].Rows.Count - 1;
                    nRow++)
                {
                    dTotal = dTotal + 
                        Convert.ToDouble(dsDetail.Tables["OrderDetails"].Rows[nRow]["Amount"].ToString());
                }
            }
            catch //(Exception ex)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            lblTotal.Text = String.Format("{0:#,###,##0.00}", dTotal);
        }
```

Comment: What kind of application you are targeting, may be there is formatting  available for column.

Comment: Take a look at [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

For money or currency format you need to use `C`

Thus change your code as

```
 lblTotal.Text = dTotal.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

or

```
 lblTotal.Text = String.Format("{0:C}", dTotal);
```

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
lblTotal.Text = dTotal.ToString("C");
```

Do not forget that this uses the default cultureinfo and displays the default currency. You can change this behaviour by also providing an instance of `CultureInfo`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shxtf045.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) object and pass in the target culture to `String.Format`, this will then display currencies and other strings using the correct culture information:

```
var cultureInfo = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE"); // for example, the German culture info will give you the commas for thousand separators instead of the decimal point
lblTotal.Text = String.Format(cultureInfo, "{0:C}", dTotal);
```

Reference for `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.createspecificculture.aspx
Reference for the above overload of `String.Format`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7.aspx

This section might be worth a read from the `String.Format` documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx#Format_Culture